# Travelling with Greyhound buses in Canada

Tags: canada, greyhound

New traveler with Greyhound buses,

I having a tough time figuring out a few things.

1) I'm trying to order two discount tickets (ISIC) from their website but for some reason only one ticket registers the discount?

Ordering one ticket at a time seems very tedious, is there a better way to do this?

For what I have found ordering directly from the web site is the cheapest way for buying a ticket, is this correct? Would the prices differ drastically if I order at the bus station and not in advance?

2)I tried using the app but it does not have an option for students (the ISIC not Student Advantage) and checking a bus from Montreal to Ottawa throws 8888$ for a one way ticket so I assume it's a bug..

Do Canadians use a different app?

I'm sorry if I'm missing obvious things I'm not from Canada and have never traveled the north America area by bus/train.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work for [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/), a bus booking app based in Montreal. We currently (August 2018) don't support Greyhound Canada's ISIC discount (hopefully we can soon). We do have some tools that may help you compare and find other bus companies where available, and search across various stops within each city.

It's odd that you aren't able to book two ISIC tickets on Greyhound.ca but I'm seeing the same thing. Note that Greyhound.ca has entirely different mobile and desktop websites, you could try both. I suppose you could book each ticket separately if nothing else works.

AFAIK the Greyhound App is only supported on the US side, it may work for buses crossing the border but likely doesn't work for Greyhound Canada within Canada.

Tickets usually cost more close to departure, how much varies by route. The maximum price you'll have to pay should match the "Standard Fare" displayed on greyhound.ca. More significantly, buses often sell out on weekends and other peak travel times, so consider booking ahead.

Also note that Greyhound is cancelling all routes west of Sudbury Ontario at the end of October 2018.

Comment: Are you sure that ticket purchase guarantees a seat/protection against sell outs?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk true it's no guarantee but it normally works. If you don't book ahead and the bus is sold out you have no chance of getting on. Regarding not being able to board when you *do* have a ticket, Greyhound has been making an effort to not oversell their buses. You can still run into operational issues where there are more passengers than seats but that's increasingly rare.